401K Rollover Tax Question
I recently rolled over my employee 401k to an IRA at a different financial institution. In that 401k, I had made both taxable and nontaxable contributions. Since retiring, I’ve been receiving required minimum distributions, and the 1099R always shows  part of the distribution is nontaxable.
It is my understanding that the new financial institution is not responsible for tracking which part of my future distributions will be taxable and which will be nontaxable and that I must do this myself.
My problem is that the original financial institution will not tell me the amount of my employee contributions. They have that information or they wouldn’t be able to prepare the 1099R’s. The customer service people will not help. They think that the new institution will track it. I do not know much tax law, but I’m concerned that I need to get this fixed asap. The entire 401K went into an IRA over a month ago.
What should I do to make this major financial institution give me the information I need and how do I track the information to report to the IRS?
Thanks so much for any information you can provide!  I’m worried sick.

This is something that should have been on your statements. You can calculate the proportions based on the prior year distributions, but that wouldn't be precise.

When you say "nontaxable contributions", do you mean after-tax contributions to the Traditional 401k? Or do you mean Roth 401k contributions?

Once you get the 'incoming' basis you put in form 8606 in your return, and from then on it chains from year to year: 'remainder' on 2024 8606 is used in 2025, 2025 is used in 2026, etc. It's like cap-loss carryforwards, except those are used up when you make cap gains (and if you never make cap gains on your investments you're in bad shape) while IRA basis bunny-like keeps going and going and going ....

@dave_thompson_085: You do not need to complete Form 8606 just for a rollover from 401k, nor do you need to complete it every future year, unless you make a nondeductible contribution, distribution, or conversion that year.

Yes. I meant after tax contributions.
And unfortunately the information is not shown anywhere on prior year statement

Also since I’m retired I need to make distributions every year from now on

I don’t have any records. My contributions have gone back for almost 50 years. I stupidly was relying on the plan administrator to keep that information

You could have split the pre-tax and after-tax funds as part of the rollover -- your rollover out of 401(k) will consist of both pre-tax and after-tax funds, prorated, but you can choose to have the pre-tax part go to Traditional IRA and the after-tax part go to Roth IRA. However, since you have already rolled over, I believe it's too late.

Absent cooperation from your 401k plan, you'll need to go back to your contributions and calculate how much after tax contributions you've made. It should be reported on your payslips and 401k statements. From that you'll need to deduct the nontaxable distributions. What's left would be your remaining basis in your IRA which you'd then need to track, prorating your distributions.
This is a good example why after tax contributions without an immediate Roth conversion are a very very bad idea.

And if I understand how it works correctly, after tax contributions don't have any tax advantage over a buy and hold strategy (if you don't sell any of your holdings until retirement, you get just as much tax deferment as if they were in a 401(k)).

@Acccumulation after tax contributions are much worse - you get the same basis as taxable accounts, but the gains are taxed as ordinary income instead of capital gains.

Is there a way to force the plan administrator to give me the information?

Subpoena? But they should have statements back for 7 years, so you can start with asking that.
